# Which class has getSize() in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

How to get the total no of products in our custom filters as below.

Desktops(54)

i believe its `getSize()`, but not sure where it is used in Magento2?

Is it from `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`??

Comment: Please don't change drastically the question once you get an answer. If you have a follow up question, please ask it separately linking this question if needed.

Answer (score 2):

**In the case of a database collection** (which is your case), it comes from `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb` :

```
public function getSize()
{
    if ($this->_totalRecords === null) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

**In the case of a simple collection (not from the database)**, it comes from `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`:

```
public function getSize()
{
    $this->load();
    if ($this->_totalRecords === null) {
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getItems());
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

NB: **there's a few exceptions** for instance the Magento 2 reports collection overrides the `getSize()` method in `Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection`

Comment: I have updated the answer with code Raphael, but my fun doesnt seem to be called and i just get filters without count